# Programatically select item in Listbox in PySimpleGUI

Tags: python-3.x, pysimplegui

Is there a way to programmatically select items in PySimpleGUI's `ListBox`?

I want to advance the selected item when a key in the keyboard is pressed.

Comment: What do you mean "programmatically"? Are you asking for example you have a list box of Countries and if the user has that Listbox selected and presses C it takes them to the first C ex. Canada? Or are you asking if a user filling out a field and presses ex. A it automatically chooses the list item that you have associated with "A"?

Comment: User presses right key and then the next item is selected in the listbox, but any of these examples would work for me. All i need to know is how to tell my listbox which item in the listbox should be selected without using the mouse

Comment: Method `set_value` of `sg.Listbox` to set listbox highlighted choices.

Comment: or option `set_to_index` in method `update` of `sg.Listbox` to highlights the item(s) indicated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Method `set_value` or `update` to set items choices.

```py
from random import choice
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.theme("DarkBlue")
sg.set_options(font=('Courier New', 12))

data = [
    'Ronald Reagan', 'Abraham Lincoln', 'George Washington', 'Andrew Jackson',
    'Thomas Jefferson', 'Harry Truman', 'John F. Kennedy', 'George H. W. Bush',
    'George W. Bush', 'John Quincy Adams', 'Garrett Walker', 'Bill Clinton',
    'Jimmy Carter', 'John Adams', 'Theodore Roosevelt', 'Frank Underwood',
    'Woodrow Wilson',
]

layout = [
    [sg.Listbox(data, size=(max(map(len, data))+2, 10), key='LISTBOX')]
]

window = sg.Window('Title', layout, finalize=True)
listbox = window['LISTBOX']

while True:
    event, values = window.read(timeout=500)
    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break
    if event == '__TIMEOUT__':
        index = choice(range(len(data)))
        listbox.update(set_to_index=[index], scroll_to_index=index)

window.close()
```